# How should I approach "context" on my developer system?

Tags: sites-9

I'm setting up a Sites 9 system for personal research using a developer license. The "default" scenario seems to be to run the context service. As far as I can gather, DXA will expect this, unless I explicitly configure it to use ADF instead for context.

The documentation for setting up the context service includes having support whitelist your IP address and downloading a repository (presumably device data and the like). As a developer licensee, will they do this for me?

Obviously, full-on support for context is interesting if I want to experiment with those features, but if I want to focus on other things, it's overkill. As far as I can see, the context service starts OK and appears to run without problems even though I haven't downloaded the repository. Is it designed to run like this? Can I use it to "have context" even though my context is presumably less rich, or am I better off just switching it off and using ADF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DXA will work just fine if you have the service registered and running. You don't need to seed the database (by whitelisting and running the seed script), especially for development purposes as it's a hassle.

Comment: I eventually ended up switching to ADF. See https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/20372/129