# How to stop DXA (Java) from using the context service

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2

When setting up DXA 2.2 I accepted the default setting to use the context service. I don't want to go to the trouble of setting up the context service to work properly, so now I'm trying to configure DXA to use ADF instead.

In `dxa.properties` I have set:

```
dxa.web.adf.enabled=true
```

yet still I get exceptions like this:

> com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientHttpError: Unable to get response from OData service: No Response.
>       com.sdl.odata.client.util.ODataClientUtils.buildException(ODataClientUtils.java:93)
>       com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:216)
>       com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.callEndpoint(BasicEndpointCaller.java:89)
>       com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getODataResponse(DefaultODataClient.java:141)
>       com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.getEntity(DefaultODataClient.java:69)
>       com.sdl.context.odata.client.ODataContextEngineProxy.resolve(ODataContextEngineProxy.java:107)
>       com.sdl.context.odata.client.CachingContextEngine.resolve(CachingContextEngine.java:61)
>       com.sdl.context.odata.client.api.ODataContextEngine.resolve(ODataContextEngine.java:46)

Are there other configurations I need to make to be free of the context service? Also - am I correct in wanting to disable it, or is this a problem I could solve in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enabling these following properties in **dxa.properties** file

```
#adf.context.provider - Activates ADF instead of Context Service for context claims.
spring.profiles.active=adf.context.provider
spring.profiles.include=adf.context.provider
```

ADF is needed for XPM Session Preview, Experience Optimization and Context Expressions. Values: [true, false]:

> dxa.web.adf.enabled=true

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Velu. My system now works.